# My bootstrap carousel only has indicators. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is the first time I've ever used bootstrap. My bootstrap carousel only has indicators. Could this be because I haven't specified pictures yet.

See the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1" />
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .jumbotron{
            background-color:#2E2D88;
            color:white;
        }
        .tab-content{
            border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .nav-tabs{
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="slide1">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Great food</h1>
                            <p>Taste what keeps people coming back</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Order for delivery, carry out, or catering</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide2">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Great prices</h1>
                            <p>A good meal doesn't have to cost an arm and a leg</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Order for delivery, carry out, or catering</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </div>
        <p>
            Blah blaha blahb lbahlbahbabablah balha blha blah blah
        </p>
    </div>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Related concerns: I'm not sure if I should be using bootstrap 4 or 3. I've heard bootstrap 4 compiles with sass but I don't know what that is. Can someone with more experience with this framework help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this working until I used examples from https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/.

Here is what I came up with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1" />
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .jumbotron{
            background-color:#3e4fa9;
            border-radius:0px;
            color:white;
        }
        .tab-content{
            border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .nav-tabs{
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/sampledining.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h3>Great food</h3>
                    <p>Taste what keeps people coming back</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Order for delivery, carry out, or catering</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/samplegyros7.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h3>Great prices</h3>
                    <p>A good meal doesn't have to cost an arm and a leg</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Order for delivery, carry out, or catering</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <p>
            blah blah blah
        </p>
    </div>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to link your images in the carousel-inner class.

check this for more details :

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h